# Данные не записываются в файл при помощи функций file.write()

Tags: python, python-3.x

file = open('sample.txt', 'w')

file.write('Привет мир!')

file.close()

при использований этого кода файл не перезаписывается(данные не вставляются в файл) а просто открывается этот файл

Comment: *>>просто открывается этот файл* - что это значит?

Comment: когда выполняю этот код через консоль он ну, простооткрывается как после двойного нажатия по икогке текстокого файла

Comment: @sswwss, как именно запускаете? В cmd пишете `имя_файла.py`? Попробуйте `python имя_файла.py`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте указать параметр `encoding` при открытии файла:

```py
open('sample.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

***Пример:***

```py
def main():
    with open('sample.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write('Привет мир!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```